# Email To Case creating new cases when responding

Tags: email2case, service-cloud-console

Service Cloud Experts:

I’m, facing an issue in salesforc email to case - when creating a case manually in salesforce org, and then sending a mail via salesforce, the user gets that mail. As soon as they answer to that mail, it doesn’t assign it to the case, but create a new case.

When I now write a new mail from the original case which I created and the user answers it, it assigned the mail correctly to the case.

So only the first mail is not assigned correctly. Anybody an idea?

Already checked:

- Ref ID is disabled and New Threading method activated
- The first mail doesn’t have a references or in-reply-to ID, but as soon as somebody
  answers, the mail which I sent from the same case object get’s one
- Everthing based on email-to-case

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour).  Including a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful.

Comment: that initial email to customer -- which SFDC process is generating it? Is it coming from one of the default behaviors defined in `Support Settings`?  Auto-Response rules? WFR, PB, Flow or Apex?

Comment: @cropredy It's coming from a Flow. But I also tried WFR, PB, Auto Response Rules and Case Creation Email via Support Settings and was the same behaviour.

Comment: The initial email needs to be associated with the source Case.  Are you sending it in the Flow as an Email Alert that is defined to use Case as its target object?

Comment: @cropredy Yes the email is sent through email alert, in a subflow. How can I assign the email to the target case object?
See Anwer for Picture

Comment: Your email alert looks OK - assuming `var_caseId` is the Case that all emails are to be threaded for